# Unable to exclude net.minidev:json-smart:2.3 from gradle dependencies

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle, spring-boot-test, gradlew

While we are trying to exclude json-smart from build.gradle file, we can still see that the dependency is downloaded n seen under the gradle dependencies.

After excluding the json-smart dependency the dependency tree looks like as mentioned below. Gradle dependencies tree:

```
+--- org. springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.2.10.RELEASE
|      +---  org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.2.10.RELEASE (*)
|      +---  org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:2.2.10.RELEASE
|     |     \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.2.10.RELEASE (*)
|     +--- org. springframework.boot: spring-boot-test-autoconfigure :2.2.10. RELEASE
|     |    +--- org.spingframework.boot:spring-boot-test:2.2.10.RELEASE (*)
|     |     \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure :2.2.10.RELEASE (*)
|     +--- com.jayway.jsaonpath:jsonpath:24.0
|     |    +--- net.minidev:json-smart:2.3
|     |    |    \---net minidev: accessor3smart:l.2
|     |     |         \---org.ow2 asm:asm: 5.04
```

Exclude code from the gradle properties file. Gradle properties:

```
implementation ("org. springframework.boot: spring-boot-starter -test : ${springBootVersion} ") {
    exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter -tomcat'
    exclude group: 'org. apache. tomcat’
    exclude group: org. apache. tomcat.embed'
    exclude module: net. minidev:json-smart
}
```

Can someone help me to understand how to exclude the dependency from the gradle.properties file?